# Linq query count

Tags: sql-server, linq

```
select count(tblVV.VNme) as total, 
      tblvV.VNme
from tblVV
inner join tblRV
on tblVV.MID=tblRV.ID
inner join tblRe
on tblRV.RID=tblRe.RID
where tblRe.StartDate>= '2016-07-01 00:00:00' and
    tblRe.EndDate<= '2016-07-31 23:59:59' and
    tblRe.Reg= 'uk' and
    tblRV.RegNo='BR72' and
    tblVV.VNme <>''
group by tblVV.VNme
```

For the above query I get:

```
total Vame
1     DDSB
11    MV
```

The above SQL query shows me correct data so now i try to convert above query to linq query

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetVo(string RegNo)
{
    string data = "[";
    try
    {
         Ts1 DB = new Ts1();
         var re = (from vehvoila in DB.tblVV
                   join regveh in DB.tblRV on vehvoila.MID equals regveh.ID
                   join reg in DB.tblReg on regveh.RID equals reg.RID
                   where regveh.RegNo == RegNo &&
                         vehvoila.Vame != ""
                   group vehvoila by vehvoila.Vame into g
                   select new
                   {  
                       VNme = g.Key,
                       cnt = g.Select(t => t.Vame).Count()
                    }).ToList();

    if (re.Any())
    {
        data += re.ToList().Select(x => "['" + x.Vame + "'," + x.cnt + "]")
          .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
    }
    data += "]";
}
```

linq  query show me return data like this

```
[['DDSB',1],['DPSB',1],['DSB',109],['MV',39],['PSB',1]]
```

Whereas I want data this

```
[['DDSB',1],['MV',11]]
```

Now the data which return SQL query is correct so how I correct linq query

**Note**: forget fromdate,todate,region parameter in SQL query . because I have page in which I put dropdown and fromdate and todate picker and there is button so when I select values  i.e. UK, and dates then data is display in table then when I click on any row in table then I want to get this data  in `data +=”]”;`

actually above linq query work behind  clicking on row

```
total Vame
1     DDSB
11    MV
```

Comment: yes i have problem which is still not solve @GiladGreen

Comment: i think i explain already what i want to get

Comment: i want this result.. [['DDSB',1],['MV',11]]

Comment: In the SQL you grouped on two columns whereas in the LINQ group is created on only one column, so you see different data. BTW What is wrong with your table and column names??

Comment: i say that from sql query i get correct data so when i convert this query to linq query then i got wrong data so there is some problem with linq query @GiladGreen

Comment: @wonderbell check update

Comment: i already paste latest linq query @GiladGreen

Comment: @GiladGreen check update question please

Comment: @user6628729 - I didn't understand your update

Comment: @user6628729 - ya you can have a stored procedure in database and then call it. But I think you should carefully debug and see what exactly is being executed with what parameters and then you'll find the problem

Comment: @GiladGreen problem solved thanku

Comment: @user6628729 - You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it all like this:

```
Ts1 db = new Ts1();
var result = (from vehvoila in db.tblVV
              join regveh in db.tblRV on vehvoila.MID equals regveh.ID
              join reg in db.tblReg on regveh.RID equals reg.RID
              where reg.StartDate >= new DateTime(2016, 7, 1) &&
                    reg.EndDate < new DateTime(2016, 8, 1) &&
                    reg.Reg == "uk" &&
                    regveh == "BR72" &&
                    vehvoila != ""
              group vehvoila by vehvoila.Vame into g
              select $"[{g.Key},{g.Count()}]");

var data = $"[{string.Join(",", result)}]";
```

1. Because you only use the result for the creation of the string in the `select` I just return the string formatted for a single item and then later used `string.Join` instead of using the `.Aggregate` - I think a bit cleaner
2. The `$"{}"` syntax is the C# 6.0 string interpolation
3. In the condition of the `EndDate` I decided to use `<` instead of the `<=` with the change of the date - At least in oracle when you partition the table by date it is better for performance - maybe also in sql server

Without string interpolation:

```
Ts1 db = new Ts1();
var result = (from vehvoila in db.tblVV
              join regveh in db.tblRV on vehvoila.MID equals regveh.ID
              join reg in db.tblReg on regveh.RID equals reg.RID
              where reg.StartDate >= new DateTime(2016, 7, 1) &&
                    reg.EndDate < new DateTime(2016, 8, 1) &&
                    reg.Reg == "uk" &&
                    regveh == "BR72" &&
                    vehvoila != ""
              group vehvoila by vehvoila.Vame into g
              select new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(g => string.Format("[{0},{1}]",g.Key, g.Count));

var data = string.Format("[{0}]",string.Join(",", result));
```

Comment: this show error on Error 3 ; expected 
Error 5 ; expected 
Error 4 Invalid expression term ')' 
on  select string.Format("[{0},{1}]",g.Key, g.Count()));